# Lua unpack() messing arguments

Tags: lua

I have this test function which simply prints values passed to it

```
function test1(...)
  for k, v in ipairs(arg) do
    print(v)    
  end
end

function test2(...)
  for k, v in pairs(arg) do
    print(v)    
  end
end

-- GOOD behavior
test1(1, 2, 3, 4) -- produces 1 2 3 4
test2(1, 2, 3, 4) -- produces 1 2 3 4

-- BAD behavior
test1( unpack({1,2}), 3, 4) -- produces 1 3 4
test2( unpack({1,2}), 3, 4) -- produces 1 3 4 3
```

Can someone explain this behavior to me ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This behavior is not specific to `unpack`.
The [Lua Reference Manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.4) says:

> "Both function calls and vararg expressions can result in multiple values. If a function call is used as a statement (see §3.3.6), then its return list is adjusted to zero elements, thus discarding all returned values. If an expression is used as the last (or the only) element of a list of expressions, then no adjustment is made (unless the expression is enclosed in parentheses). **In all other contexts, Lua adjusts the result list to one element, either discarding all values except the first one or adding a single nil if there are no values.**"

(my emphasis)

Comment: For the curious: [where all can a list of expressions occur in Lua?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31782250/183120)