# Redis Lua Script Unpack Returning Different Results

Tags: lua, redis

Setup by running sadd a b c

When I execute this code against the set a
keystoclear1 has a single value of "b" in it.
keystoclear2 as both values in it.

```
local keystoclear = unpack(redis.call('smembers', KEYS[1]))

redis.call('sadd', 'keystoclear1', keystoclear)

redis.call('sadd', 'keystoclear2', unpack(redis.call('smembers', KEYS[1])))
```

I am by no means a lua expert, so I could just have some strange behavior here, but I would like to know what is causing it.

I tested this on both the windows and linux version of redis, with redis-cli and the stackexchange.redis client. Same behavior in all cases. This is a trivial example, I actually would like to store the results of the unpack because I need to perform several operations with it.

UPDATE: I understand the issue.

[table.unpack() only returns the first element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32439689/table-unpack-only-returns-the-first-element)

> Lua always adjusts the number of results from a function to the circumstances of the call. When we call a function as a statement, Lua discards all of its results. When we use a call as an expression, Lua keeps only the first result. We get all results only when the call is the last (or the only) expression in a list of expressions.

Answer (score 2):

This case is slightly different from the one you referenced in your update. In this case `unpack` (may) return several elements, but you only store one and discard the rest. You can get other elements if you use `local keytoclear1, keytoclear2 = ...`, but it's much easier to store the table itself and unpack it as needed:

```
local keystoclear = redis.call('smembers', KEYS[1])
redis.call('sadd', 'keystoclear1', unpack(keystoclear))
```

As long as `unpack` is the last parameter, you'll get all the elements that are present in the table being unpacked.

Comment: try call `redis.call('sadd', 'keystoclear1', (unpack(keystoclear)))`

Comment: @moteus, this will give you just the first element in `keystoclear`, which is what the OP has now.